# Handling of a Dictionary Element in the context of "Array" notation

Tags: swift, dictionary, closures

Struggling to achieve 2) below.

In the examples below, `T` is a concrete type. `T` could be `String` but the examples would then look even stranger.

1. Works:

   ```
    var v = [         // v is a Dictionary with two Dictionary<String, T>.Element's
        "x": T("x"),  // Unfortunate since "x" has to be repeated    
        "y": T("y") 
    ]
   ```
2. Desired syntax, intended to do the same as 1). Does not work:

   ```
    var v = [        
        { let s = "x";             // Attempting to use a closure to "inline" the local variable s
          return (s: T(name: s))   // Using a tuple to return the Dictionary<String, T>.Element
        }(),
        { let s = "y";   
          return (s: T(name: s))
        }()
    ]
   ```

*Xcode error for 2): Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional*

3. Trying to fix 2) with explicit types. Does not work.

   ```
    var v : Dictionary<String, T>.Element = [        
        { let s = "x";             
          return Dictionary<String, T>.Element(s: T(name: s))
        }(),
        { let s = "y";             
          return Dictionary<String, T>.Element(s: T(name: s))
        }()
    ]
   ```

*Xcode error for 3): Dictionary of type 'Dictionary<String, T>' cannot be initialized with array literal*

This "MWE" example admittedly looks weird, but I am trying to understand how, in general, it may be possible to use a Dictionary Element (Key and Value *together, as a hole*) as if it were (informally speaking) an element of an Array.

Comment: So T is a specific concrete type or otherwise what is the definition of T?

Comment: You may substitute String for T in the above example, although it makes the example look a bit weirder.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand that.

Comment: I just edited and tried to clarify in the intro to this answer. What I mean is: If you instead of T use String in the examples, the problem "remains".

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with a syntax like that?

Comment: In general, imagine you are introducing elements of type T into a convenience dictionary which is constructed by the programmer by hand, as in 1). The constructor for T copies the key's String "value" (eg. as a field in a T-struct), but you wish to not have to type that explicit key's "value" twice for each entry, since that is error prone: In the future, should you desire to change the key's "values"; you must also change the key's "values" in the call to the constructor T().

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of keys and you want to create a dictionary out of it by mapping each key to another type, I'd suggest this way:

```swift
let keys = ["x", "y", "z"]
let dict = Dictionary(
    uniqueKeysWithValues: keys.map { key in (key, T(key)) }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now keys are disassociated from other contents of T. Admittedly my example does not highlight this problem. But imagine you have elements like "sun" : T("sun", foodToEatOnSunnyDays). Think about the Dictionary being a convenience user dictionary, where elements are introduced by hand, and the content of key and value should be readily cognizable.

Comment: If you have some detached homogenous data that is associated with the type T and is identified by the same keys of the dictionary, perhaps it would be better to start with a dictionary in the first place: `["sun": foodToEatOnSunnyDays, "snow": foodToEatOnSnowyDays]`. And then map this dictionary to `[String: T]`.

Comment: That is a good idea and may work in come contexts, but in others it may pose the same problem of coordination of contents in different places.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure exactly what you want but I thought I add this solution to see if it is correct or at least something to discuss further

```
struct T {
    let name: String
}

extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == T {
    init(values: Key...) {
        self = values.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1] = T(name: $1) }
    }
}

var dict = Dictionary(values: "x", "y")
```

An alternative solution when the `init` needs to be dynamic

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == T {
    init(values: Key..., construct: (Key) -> T) {
        self = values.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1] = construct($1) }
    }
}

var dict = Dictionary(values: "x", "y") { T(name: $0)}
```

Comment: This would not let me allow multiple inserts in a Dictionary in one statement as in the example 1). I can see however how to modify it to accept multiple parameters for each Element eg. ```("x", T("x", 4))``` and multiple Elements [("x", T("x", 4)), ("y", T("y", 7)), ...]. So it comes close. Thanks

Comment: Looks to me like you have completely changed the requirements now

Comment: Maybe my MWE was to elementary? However, Im really after being able to do example 1). But, true, T("x") should be changed to T("x", <other params>).

Comment: I will add another solution that takes a closure

Answer (score 0):

Sufficient solution:

```
var v = Dictionary<String, T>(uniqueKeysWithValues:
     [ { let s = "x"; return (s, T(s)) }(),
       { let s = "y"; return (s, T(s)) }(),
     ]
 )
```

That means, that you must use explicit `Dictionary` constructor, using `uniqueKeysWithValues`

Comment: Here you are writing the value twice even though you said you wanted to avoid exactly that. Shouldn’t it at least be `let s = "x"; return (s, T(s))`?

Comment: correct! mistake, many thx, correcting it.